# Threejs: make custom shader match the standard rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, fragment-shader, buffer-geometry

For performance reasons I need to display hundred of moving tetrahedrons in a scene. There for I use instancedbuffergeometry which requires a custom shader.

The scene also contains objects with regular geometry (non-buffer) and some lights (I prepared boiled-down snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/negan/xs3k1yz4/ ).

My problem is that the tetrahedrons are not shaded such that their lighting plausibly fits to the rest of the scene. The reason is probably the primitive shader I built:

```html
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 offset;
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec3 vNormal;
void main() {
 vColor = color;
 vNormal = normalMatrix * vec3(normal);
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
    modelViewMatrix *
    vec4(position*1.0+offset,1.0);
}
</script>
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
 varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec3 vNormal;

 void main() {  
  float di = 0.4*dot(vNormal,normalize(vec3(1.,1.,0.)))+0.4*dot(vNormal,normalize(vec3(1.,0.,1.)));
  di = di+0.2;
  vec4 vColor2= vColor*vec4(1.0,1.,1.,0.2)*di;
  gl_FragColor = vColor2;// adjust the alpha
 }
</script>
```

Is there a way to make the custom shader fit the lights I defined in the scene? The shader also renders the faces in such a way which does not make the impression of directed light. I'd rather like to have single faces lit evenly rather that have the color interpolated from the vertices but I was unable to achieve that.

Any pointer or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a gist of the full fragment and vertex shader source](https://gist.github.com/AndrewRayCode/debd68861317055baf78120b7face413) for a Three.js MeshPhongMaterial shader, as of r83.

Three.js builds shaders using a string concatenation system, so figuring out the source of a shader from looking at the Three.js source will be almost impossible.

The above Gist was generated by installing the [shader editor Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shader-editor/ggeaidddejpbakgafapihjbgdlbbbpob?hl=en), going to a Three.js example page that has a MeshPhongMaterial [like this one](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_variations_phong.html) and using the shader editor to inspect the full source of a running shader program:

[image: shader editor source]

Three.js passes all default uniforms, like lighting data, to all shader programs, so if you create a custom shader with the above Gist code, lights, bones, etc, will all work automatically.

I would take the full source code and add your logic in manually, literally adding the result of your calculations to the existing `gl_FragColor = ...`

In the future, my tool [ShaderFrog](http://shaderfrog.com/app) will let you automatically add any Three.js shader feature (lights, bones, morph targets, etc) to any custom shader. ShaderFrog can already combine any shaders together automatically, but I haven't done the manual work needed to fully support Three features yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's InstancedMesh module for three.js . It allows mesh instancing without using shader materials. It patches the existing material.
https://github.com/pailhead/three-instanced-mesh